# How to redirect users from an old path ,in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I want to redirect users from an old path, where should I put the route provider module? Or path redirect? Inside angular-route.js or app.js?

Comment: Add some code, so we can help you.

Comment: In general redirects are done from the server-side. Please provide more explaination of what you are doing and what you want to accomplish.